# Launch android app on screen unlock

Tags: java, android

I want to build a lock screen replacement application. Is there any way to create a listener/service that would launch my app whenever the user wakes up/unlocks the screen?

Comment: Android does not currently support replacing the default lock screen. Any app currently on the market that claims to do so is making use of a security loophole and is in no way secure. Read this [**thread**](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/9m36tsMA628) for more information on the subject. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks @AlexLockwood I understand android doesnt support building lock screen replacements at this time but I'm looking to take advantage of one of those security loopholes as other apps do

Comment: Haha... OK then your best bet would be to look at the source code for existing applications (see imran khan's answer below). There aren't many tutorials/sample code on the internet explaining how to do this sort of thing and it is certainly not something you would find on the Android developers site or in an Android development book. Further, it is not really common knowledge for people on StackOverflow... the people who write these apps have very specific knowledge on a subject that requires a lot of analysis to understand... so chances are you won't get a helpful answer here on StackOverflow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See source code of  [mylockforandroid](http://code.google.com/p/mylockforandroid/source/browse/) and  you will need use [DeviceAdminReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html) for disableing default android screenlock.

for starting your activity when user unlock screen register an `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON` and `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` as:

add this code in manifast.xml register ScreenReceiver as:

```
<receiver android:name=".ScreenReceiver">
 <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"/>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
 </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

and add an ScreenReceiver.java as:

```
 public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))
         {
            Intent intent = new Intent();  
            intent.setClass(context, ScreenLockActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);          
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: **Step 1:** User boots device into safe mode. **Step 2:** User uninstalls the "mylockforandroid" application. **Step 3:** The user now has access to any application that the "mylockforandroid" application claimed it had "locked". So the answer is "no", there is no way to reliably implement your own screen lock application. Sorry.

Comment: I tried looking at the mylockforandroid code but it functions very poorly on newer phones. It kept crashing for me or not working at all

Comment: @AlexLockwood : ok i agree with can u tell me how make an screen lock for Android device plz???

Comment: Do you mean an unreliable screen lock application? Because you'd have to implement your own firmware in order to write a reliable one.

Comment: @Peter : as your question i have give u mylockforandroid link by which u can see how we launch our screenlock activity on Device screen on and one more think without device manager you are not able to disable default android screenlock.thanks

Comment: @AlexLockwood : u means all screenlocks like android Screen Unlock,ThrottleLock ,StrongBox Lock etc are unreliable screen lock application? ok i agee with u.ask this question to @ Peter why he want to create an unreliable screen lock application

Comment: I think your answer is helpful in making an insecure screen lock, that is all I am saying. The whole purpose of Android is to provide an OS that guarantees that the user has control over his or her device. Third party apps are no exception... any app you install will ***not*** provide a secure means of locking other applications.

Comment: That said, I can imagine certain cases in which your answer might be helpful. I'm betting that not many people know *how* to boot into safe mode and bypass this sort of thing... and this is probably why the app that you mentioned in your answer is popular. But when it comes down to it, apps simply cannot lock other apps in a secure fashion.

Comment: I edited my answer and I upvoted your answer too. I wasn't kidding when I said "don't delete your answer". I think providing that source code was helpful for those who need to implement some sort of "false" security mechanism that 95% of users won't be able to bypass. But I also think that its important to mention that this sort of thing shouldn't be relied on as it goes against the design goals of the Android operating system. No hard feelings, by the way :)

Comment: @imrankhan So I implemented your code and added a println to see if it works and it does. But Now im trying to launch an activity from where you said "//start your activity from here" but I can't figure out how. Any help?

Comment: @Peter : see my edit answer.try it known and if u get any issue then let me known

Comment: @imrankhan I tried that code and when i unlock my phone the activity never started

Comment: @Peter : try this https://sites.google.com/site/imrankhanandroid/Screenunlocktest.rar?attredirects=0&d=1

Comment: @imrankhan That works thank you, I was missing the piece in the manifest!

Answer (score 8):

I believe you are looking for the [`ACTION_USER_PRESENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT) intent action.

> public static final String ACTION_USER_PRESENT
>
> Since: API Level 3
>   Broadcast Action: Sent when the user is present after device wakes up (e.g when the keyguard is gone).

That said, Android does not support replacing the lock screen at this time. Any apps on the market that claim to do this make use of security loop holes and are not secure. [**You can read this thread for more information.**](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/9m36tsMA628) (in particular, you should read Mark Murphy's posts). Sorry.