# Launch unlock screen

Tags: android, unlock

I need to trigger the unlock screen directly, from an Activity launched with the `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` flag.

I don't want to start a new activity without the `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` lock, nor I want to re-launch the same activity removing the flag.

I don't want neither to prompt the user the "confirm credentials screen" using the `KeyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent()`. But I explicitly need to launch the system unlock screen and once unlocked, jump back to the same Activity, with the unlocked device.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803069/android-unlock-screen-intent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172605/launch-android-app-on-screen-unlock

Comment: I've already make a search in Stackoverflow posts;

- The 1st link doesn't help, since the disableKeyguard() method is deprecated.
- In the 2nd link, the question is about doing something AFTER the screen is unlocked.