# Android service running but overlay activity flicks and disappears

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-service, android-broadcast

Background info: I'm trying to create a service. I create it in my main activity. I know the service is running because the notification is showing. So the service doesn't stop at any point.

What i want to happen: when the screen is locked/turned off i want a certain activity to be displayed for when the screen is turned back on.

What is happening: first, When the screen is turned back on the main activity shows and then the activity i want shows over that. I dont want the main activity to show at all when the screen is turned on .

Then i changed a few things: and now the desired activity flickers on the main screen and then vanishes. It seems very unreliable and only comes a few times.

That should be enough info, here is the code so far (specifically onReceive())

```
public class OverlayService extends Service{

//IN THIS CLASS CHECK WHETHER LOCK BUTTON WAS PRESSED OR IF PHONE WHEN TO SLEEP.. UPON AWAKENING START THE OVERLAY ACTIVITY...
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
private boolean isShowing = false;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

private WindowManager windowManager;
WindowManager.LayoutParams params;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    windowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    //Register receiver for determining screen off and if user is present
    mReceiver = new OverlayStateReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);

    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    makeNotification();
}

void makeNotification() {
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            //TODO change icon
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.test)
            .setContentTitle("App")
            .setContentText("service is running...")
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_LOW)
            .build();
    startForeground(1, notification);
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

public class OverlayStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            Log.i("app", "load view");
            showOverlayActivity(context);
        }
    }
}

private void showOverlayActivity(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, OverlayActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    //unregister receiver when the service is destroy
    if (mReceiver != null) {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    //TODO remove view if it is showing and the service is destroy

    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Comment: duplicate ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172605/launch-android-app-on-screen-unlock

Comment: @RafaelAdel clearly not a duplicate... mine is just a overlay activity theirs is a lock screen replacement. Did you actually read it? and besides im not asking how to do it, im asking why what i have is not working :)